# How do you embed the Alexa widget into SSL websites?

Tags: ssl, alexa-skills-kit

I found it very strange, but Alexa doesn't provide support for embed their widget on SSL websites `(https://...)`

Searching on Google I found only this solution:

```
<a href="http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/yoursite.com"><script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.mindfreakers.net/ajax/ssl?u=http://xslt.alexa.com/site_stats/js/t/a?url=yoursite.com"></script></a>
```

Since I'm suspicious about the source, could you please tell me the appropriate method to embed the Alexa widget in a SSL website?

Comment: I think we are the one who made that source, we have updated the script and it's safe to use :) for now

Comment: Also link is updated, do re-check the blog

Comment: https://www.sharingtricks.com/how-to-use-alexa-widget-with-ssl-support/3176/